# Java regular expression, first entry of tag

Tags: java, regex

I have XML of such a structure:

```
<root>
  <parent>
    <t1>...</t1>
    <t2>...</t2>
    <tagToFind>...</tagToFind>
    <tN>...</tN>
  </parent>
  <tagToFind>...</tagToFind>
</root>
```

I need to find first entry of `<tagToFind>` (actually, right sign is being inside `<parent>` tag) and replace text inside.

I try regex smth like:

```
<parent>(\s*.*\s*)*^<tagToFind>(.*)</tagToFind>
```

but still have no luck. Could anybody give a hint or right approach for solving?
Thank you!

Comment: Parse the XML document properly rather than using regex

Comment: Unfortunately I have to use regex by some reasons

Comment: Well, using an XML parser is the "right approach to solving". I wonder what those reasons are.

Comment: Using of regex is a lightweight solution with native Java facilities, I need no XML parser for my case.

Comment: XML parsers are part of the standard Java library. Creating a Document and using a simple XPath query is not heavy weight, and is a lot more readable than using a regex.

Comment: The point is that I process not only XML, it can be different type of strings, so I use generalized approach with regex'es.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, a XML parser may be the better solution.
The Regex-Issue may still be resolved using the regex given [here](https://regex101.com/r/uZ9lT4/4), which is:

```
"(.*<parent>.*?<tagToFind>)(.*?)(<\/tagToFind>.*)"
// in java we don't need to escape '/':
"(.*<parent>.*?<tagToFind>)(.*?)(</tagToFind>.*)"
```

Please note that you need to compile the pattern using [DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL). With the given regex you have one group, which is the values between the start and end of your `tagToFind`.

A minimal example that I just tested:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*<parent>.*?<tagToFind>)(.*?)(</tagToFind>.*)", Pattern.DOTALL);

String testString = "<root>\n" +
            "  <parent>\n" +
            "    <t1>...</t1>\n" +
            "    <t2>...</t2>\n" +
            "    <tagToFind>something in the tagToFind</tagToFind>\n" +
            "    <tN>...</tN>\n" +
            "  </parent>\n" +
            "  <tagToFind>...</tagToFind>\n" +
            "</root>";

Matcher m = pattern.matcher(testString);
if(m.matches()){
    System.out.println("Found string");
    System.out.println("Value: " + m.group(2));
}
```

Will output:

```
Found string
Value: something in the tagToFind
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!